# What pedals to get this effect?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

What kind of pedals should I purchase to make my guitar sound like this (Slash, Nightrain):

Comment: Please add some detail to the question so that it is searchable and useful to others.

Comment: @petilon did you make a separate account to edit this?

Answer (score 4):

The effects Slash used are a Dunlop DCR-ISR Crybaby Rack, Dunlop Heil Talk Box, Boss DD-5 Digital Delay and a Boss GE-7 Equalizer (to boost his amplifier volume in the solos when playing live).

He gets his sound from his amp since he uses a high end marshal(a Marshall JCM 2555 Silver Jubilee back then), so an amp will get you a better slash sound than anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Hussein. I did find a youtube video where Shash's guitar tech talks about the pedals. I am aiming for the tone in this particular video though, and I hope I don't have to get all the pedals Slash uses -- I couldn't afford it. If I can get just one or two pedals to get close to the tone in this video that would be great. As far as amp, I have an Orange Micro Terror.

Comment: are you interesed in simulating the tone in some software? there are many presets that will get you tones for lots of songs

Comment: @petilon as the answer points out, the tone *isn't from pedals* (aside from the delay on the lead, which you can hear clearly after the rhythm stops), a big part is the amplifier. There are pedals that aim to create a "driven amp" tone - this one is specific to the Marshall JCM: http://www.weehbo.com/products/jcm-drive/. There are forum threads on getting a "Slash tone" from Orange amps - see e.g. http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/archive/index.php?t-1038943.html

Answer (score 2):

These guys have a great video about how to sound like Slash's band Guns'n'Roses on a budget.

Here's the gear they chose:

SLASH:

- [Tone City   Angel Wing](http://bit.ly/1LRbFMw)
- [Seymour Duncan Pickup Booster](http://bit.ly/1FCn8Ga)
- [MXR Talk Box](http://bit.ly/1RRkxB9)
- [MXR Carbon Copy](http://bit.ly/1GcZdQj)
- [Epiphone 1960's Tribute Plus](http://bit.ly/1TsLn5O)
- [Marshall DSL 40C](http://bit.ly/1MscrJT)

IZZY STRADLIN:

- [Fulltone Plimsoul](http://bit.ly/1MBHRxN)
- [Epiphone Sheraton II Pro](http://bit.ly/1nwqb0G)
- [Backstar Artist 15](http://bit.ly/1QLKJe6)